# Tezos alphanet branch 'bake for' command is not available

Tags: baking, tezos-client, baker, alphanet, sandbox

I'm using sandboxed node on my local using alphanet branch (building a node on local from alphanet branch) following http://tezos.gitlab.io/mainnet/user/sandbox.html

Once nodes are up,
I run below commands to activate alphanet protocol.

```
./tezos/src/bin_client/tezos-init-sandboxed-client.sh 1
./tezos/tezos-client -l -base-dir ./tmp -addr localhost -port 18731  -block genesis activate protocol PsddFKi32cMJ2qPjf43Qv5GDWLDPZb3T3bF6fLKiF5HtvHNU7aP with fitness 1 and key activator and parameters ./tezos/scripts/protocol_parameters.json --timestamp $(TZ='AAA+1' date +%FT%TZ)
```

This commands injects the operation successfully.
Now when I try to bake this operation using below command,

```
./tezos/tezos-client -l -base-dir ./tmp -addr localhost -port 18731  bake for bootstrap1
```

it throws error saying `command not found`.

I'm able to run these commands on older version of alphanet node.

I'm trying to build something and that's why I'm not able to use below command in my application.

```
eval `./src/bin_client/tezos-init-sandboxed-client.sh 1`
```

I want to activate alphanet on my sandboxed nodes and use bake command for various operation.

Comment: Did you first `tezos-activate-alpha` with the sandboxed client?

Comment: I'm calling tezos-client originte command with alphabet protocol which injects the operation correctly to the node. Now I want to bake this operation and that's where it fails.

Comment: Please show what you are doing and what error you get, in detail. It occurs to me that `command not found` is not a tezos client error...

Answer (score 0):

There was issue with the alphanet protocol I was using. I changed the protocol and it fixed my issue.